# Android java : classify Uri text and image

Tags: java, android

The problem is how to classify when I select text file / image file it show me open text file apps or open image apps. This is actually similar like File Explorer. I don't know to classify it so I put two together. Unfortunately, the result is not I want. So I asking here for help =)

The following is the coding:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    FileInfo fileDescriptor = fileArrayListAdapter.getItem(position);
    if (fileDescriptor.isFolder() || fileDescriptor.isParent()) {
        currentFolder = new File(fileDescriptor.getPath());
        fill(currentFolder);
    } else {

        fileSelected = new File(fileDescriptor.getPath());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_FILE_SELECTED,
                fileSelected.getAbsolutePath());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        Log.i("FILE CHOOSER", "result ok");
        //finish();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileSelected), "text/*");
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileSelected), "image/*");
        startActivity(intent); 
    //  Intent intent = new Intent();



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100%, but the general way is to look at the extention of the file.  .jpg, .gif, .png, .bmp, etc are image files.  .rtf, .txt, etc are text files.  Choose the mime type based on the extention.  `MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension()` may be able to help.

Comment: Hi thanks for your concern and reply. I'm new in Android Development . How to put the MimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension() inside my code ?